# rjson reads 35-column 40-row file as one long row

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I am trying to test unicode-heavy imports of various R packages. I'm through everything but JSON because of a persisetant error: The file is read in as one long, single-row file. The file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nItH4WiIYYnerxSNdfcbyK07c-p-LEFU/view?usp=sharing).

I think I am following the instructions in the help. I have tried two approaches:

1. read the data into an object, then convert to a data frame.

```r
raw_json_data <- read_file("World Class.json")
test_json <- fromJSON(raw_json_data)
as.data.frame(test_json)
```

2. Read the file using `fromJSON()` then convert to a data frame. I happen to be using R's new pipe here, but that doesn't seem to matter.

```r
rjson_json <- fromJSON(file = "World Class.json") |> 
  as.data.frame()
```

In every attempt, I get the same result: a data frame of 1 column and 1400 variables. Is there a step I am missing in this conversion?

EDIT: I am not looking for the answer "Use package X instead". The rjson package seems to read in the JSON data, which has a quite simple structure. The problem is that the `as.data.frame()` call results in one-row, 1400-character data frame, and I'm asking wht that is.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `jsonlite` package instead.

```
library(jsonlite)

## next line gives warning: JSON string contains (illegal) UTF8 byte-order-mark!

json_data <- fromJSON("World Class.json") # from file
dim(json_data)

[1] 40 35
```

Comment: So the problem is that the complicated Unicode has a character that resin doesn’t understand?

Comment: It's a warning, so may or may not be a problem. I don't know whether it's an issue for rjson::fromJSON, the point is that jsonlite::fromJSON reads the file correctly.

Comment: Could you edit your answer in some tiny way? I hit the -1 arrow by accident and can't undo it unless the answer is edited.

Comment: OK! added a character :)